# I keep getting status 500 because of Circular structure of json

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm creating a microservice by calling another API inside this API. The other API returns the data but I keep getting this error

> This is payment Response { success: true, json: 1 } (node:31709)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular
>   structure to JSON
>       at JSON.stringify ()
>       at stringify (/Users/greatness/microservice/order/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1119:12)
>       at ServerResponse.json (/Users/alpha/setel/order/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:260:14)
>       at router.post (/Users/alpha/setel/order/src/routes/order.js:59:21)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7) (node:31709) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)

```
router.post("/order", async (req, res) => {

    let paymentResponse;

    // Im using Mongoose
    const order = new Order()

   try {
        // Call the payment API
        paymentResponse = await axios.post('http://localhost:3002/api/v1/payment', {
            order
        })

    } catch (err) {

        res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            message: err.message
        })
    }

    console.log("This is payment Response", paymentResponse.data)

    // Success change the order status to confirmed
    if (paymentResponse.data.json === 0) {
        order.status = "confirmed"
    } else {
        order.status = "declined"
    }

    order.save()
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        paymentResponse,
        order
    })
})
```

The other just returning normal json

```
router.post("/v1/payment", async (req, res) => {

    try {


        // If 0 confirmed if 1 declined
        const randomResponse = Math.round(Math.random())
        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            json: randomResponse
        })

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            message: err.message
        })
    }
})
```

What can I do? I keep getting status 500.

Regards.

Comment: How to fix it? @naga-elixir-jar

Comment: If there's any information from the response that you want to send to the user, extract that part and send. It is a big object with circular structure

Comment: Your `order` does not seem to be a POJO: since it has `.save()`, I'll guess it also contains a reference to the database, other models with which it has relationships... and you could have a circular reference anywhere in that rabbit hole. However, nothing in your question or your tags suggests which ORM you are using, so it is impossible to answer.

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar: `paymentResponse` probably cannot have a circular reference because it was reconstituted from an AJAX call (unless `axios` injects something after the request, or the response is in a non-JSON format that allows circular references, like YAML).

Comment: @Amadan I'm using mongoose

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `json` with like this:

```
res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    paymentResponse, <---
    order
})
```

The `paymentResponse` is a response object from axios, this is NOT a simple json, rather a complex JS objects with methods, properties and circular references.
What you want to do, is to send only the raw data like this:

```
res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    paymentResponse: paymentResponse.data, <--- Make sure the response from payment is valid json!
    order
})
```

Comment: I guess that should be `paymentResponse: paymentResponse.data`